# get all unique value from a sparse matrix[python/scipy]

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am trying to make a machine learning lib work together with scipy sparse matrix.

Below code is to detect if there are more than 1 class in `y` or not.Because it doesn't make sense if there is only 1 class when doing classification.

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,1])
uniques = set(y)  # get {0, 1}

if len(uniques) == 1:
    raise RuntimeError("Only one class detected, aborting...")
```

But `set(y)` not work if `y` is scipy sparse matrix.

How to efficiently get all unique value if `y` is scipy sparse matrix?

PS: I know `set(y.todense())` may work, but is cost too much memory

**UPDATE:**

```
>>> y = sp.csr_matrix(np.array([0,1,0,1,0,1]))
>>> set(y.data)
{1}
>>> y.data
array([1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 5):

Sparse matrices store their values in different ways, but usually there is a `.data` attribute that contains the nonzero values.

```
set(y.data)
```

might be all that you need.  This should work for `coo`, `csr`, `csc`.  For others you many need to convert the matrix format (e.g. `y.tocoo`).

If that does not work, give us more details on the matrix format and problems.

Comment: scipy (0.16.1), `set(y.data)`not work on win7 x64 and centos 6.5 x64

Comment: You will have to add the `0` yourself.  As you can see the `y.data` array just has the nonzero values.  That's the nature of sparse matrices.  If you don't want to use the dense version that's the best we can do.

Comment: Thanks. I think `sparse` is store each independent value in some place and only set reference in matrix before.After considering `y.data`'s struct, realize that sparse matrix need omit `0` to save space.